# How to convert a PyTorch sparse_coo_tensor into a PyTorch dense tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, sparse-matrix, tensor, torch

I create a sparse_coo tensor in PyTorch:

```
import torch

# create indices
i = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 1],
                  [2, 0, 2]])
# create values
v = torch.tensor([3, 4, 5], dtype=torch.float32)

# create sparse_coo_tensor
sparse_tensor = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(i, v, [2, 4])
```

Now I want to convert a PyTorch sparse tensor into a PyTorch dense tensor. Which function can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `to_dense` as suggested in [this example](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/sparse.html#construction) :

```
s = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(i, v, [2, 4])
s_dense = s.to_dense()
```

And by the way, the documentation is [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/sparse.html#torch.Tensor.to_dense)